# create new user role for reader

Tags: user-roles

is there a way to add a new user role?
I need two kind of readers:

1. can read all private posts
2. can read just private posts from a specific category.

Subscriber as described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) could be fair enough to satisfy the first kind of reader.
Then what I need is to define something less than subscriber, once I can test if a user has this new role for me it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this plugin should help you with what you need and more http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 1):

For 1. you can define a new role using [CapsMan plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/). You can give him the permission to edit , read and view private post.

For 2. you can use a member plugins like http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin. That could be more that you need!